# how can i access a variable defined inside a for each loop outside the loop?

Tags: php

Here is my code...

```
foreach ($relatedStories->getResults() as $story):
    $total+=$story->getEstimation();
endforeach;
```

$$relatedStories is an array of values.im summing the attribute estimation to total. 
Now i need to access the total value outside. How can i do so????

Comment: just access it. what's the problem? did you ever try to echo it?

Comment: It ain't that easy - defined in the loop, unset when loop ends (end of scope).

Answer (score 9):

Define variable `$total` outside the loop. (`$total = 0;`).